Imposible Conectar con una Base Db2 Luw
Agradezco de ante mano cualquier orientación,
antes de perder el juicio
Mi Contexto:
Windows 7 Ultimate 32 bits.
He probado mi conexió a Db2 con los siguientes softs
Toad for Db2 Freeware
SQL Manager for Db2
IBM Client Eclipse
El Estado de ODBC lo indico a continuación
User Dsn:
MazeGlBl: MazeGlBl: IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER - DB2COPY
SAMPLE:   IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER - DB2COPY
SAMPLE:   IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER - DB2COPY
sYSTEM Dsn
MazeGlBl: IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER - DB2COPY
SAMPLE:   IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER - DB2COPY
Drivers:
IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER
IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER - DB2COPY1
La String de Conexión es:
//String de Conexión
//Driver={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};
//Database=MazeGlBl;
//Hostname=Ivan-Lonco;
//Port=50000;
//Protocol=TCPIP;
//UID=db2admin;
//PWD=sa

Trazado de ODBC para Db2 Luw:
LinuxDb2OdbcCnx 1464-d0
EXIT  SQLDriverConnectW  with return code -1 (SQL_ERROR)
HDBC                0x051BEB18
HWND                0x00000000
WCHAR *             0x63738B34 [      -3] "******\ 0"
SWORD                       -3
WCHAR *             0x63738B34
SWORD                       -3
SWORD *             0x00000000
UWORD                        0 <SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT>
DIAG [08001] [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30081N  S
e ha detectado un error en las comunicaciones. 
Protocolo de comunicaciones que se está 
utilizando: "TCP/IP".  API de comunicaciones 
que se está utilizando: "SOCKETS".  
Ubicación donde se ha encontrado el error: 
"fe80::cc91:7ba8:1ac6:3724%17".  
Función de comunicación que ha detectado el error: "selectForRecvTimeout".  
Código(s) de error específico(s) del protocolo: 
"0", "*", "*".  SQLSTATE=08001

